# What is a natural French phrase for 'I've never seen you two apart'?

Tags: anglais, formulation-idiomatique

Having consulted the online dictionary, 'séparés' appears to be able to be used for  'apart'. But doesn't  'séparés' seem like the word for the romantic relationship going bad and the couple being separated? What I would like to say is that the two have always been together, no matter what they do. So like teasing, I would like to say a thing like this.

> I believe I've never seen you two apart. Maybe it's just a matter of time before a marriage?

Comment: *Un mariage serait-il pour bientôt ?* or *Il y aurait pas un mariage dans l'air ?*

Comment: @jlliagre As for the 2nd part, I would have said in a "teasing" tone: "*Est-ce qu’il y aurait **du mariage** dans l’air?*" A little different from yours. What do you think?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Yes, I hesitated between *du mariage* and *un mariage*. The former has indeed more of a teasing and colloquial tone.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. @jlliagre Can I ask you a question? What do you mean by "The former has indeed more of a teasing and colloquial tone"? My French is not advanced enough to understand why 'du mariage',  'de le mariage' in Con-gras-tue-les-chiens' phrase is considered as a teasing.

Comment: *Il y aurait un mariage dans l'air* is a direct statement, the marriage can't be but between the two persons in question while *Il y aurait **du** mariage* is indirect. "Some marriage" might be "in the air" but, which one it is is not explicitly stated.

Comment: @jlliagre To say 'some', I learned that it must be in plural for countable nouns. 'Mariage' is countable, so I thought it would be correct to say 'Il y aurait des mariages'. I'm confused why it is wrong.

Comment: Using *mariage* as uncountable is the colloquial side of the expression, and *des mariages* wouldn't make sense, there are just two people here.

Comment: Interestingly, you may find this usage of *il y a du/de la + a countable noun used as uncountable* with other words: *Il y a du penalty dans l'air* (ie, you expect the referee will give a penalty kick), *il y a de la dispute dans l'air* , *il y a du licenciement dans l'air* (ie, you expect a company will let some people go), etc.

Comment: @Greg Hi. Interestingly, the same can be said in English: "We're looking for ***some word*** {unknown/unspecified} that starts with D" vs "What are ***some words*** {multiple, an unspecified number of things} starting with H to describe someone?". What do you think?

Comment: I guess the difference is that in French, I cannot think of another use than with this phrase *il y a du/de la X" dans l'air*... That would be an interesting separate post...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some more suggestions:

> Vous ne vous quittez plus.
>
> Vous ne pouvez plus vous passer l'un de l'autre
>
> On ne vous voit plus l'un sans l'autre

A teasing way to suggest a couple (or just anyone, more generally) may be up to something in the hidden might be :

> Y a-t-il anguille sous roche ?

It is rather vague, but it is supposed to give a hint to your interlocutor that you want to know more.

EDIT: some more suggestions :

A subtle way to indirectly ask if there will be a wedding:

> J'espère que vous m'inviterez au mariage...

Using a somewhat "old style" phrase:

> Publie-t-on bientôt les bans ?

*Publier les bans* refers to the French legal obligation for the civil authorities to announce weddings officially by posting the list of them a couple of weeks before the due date.

Comment: En ce qui concerne « anguille sous roche », le TLFi ne mentionne rien de ce que j'avance maintenant : ne serait-il pas le cas que cette expression ne soit plus utilisée de nos jours sans le sous-entendu d'un contexte particulier mais qu'elle en soit venu à être utilisée avec des connotations négatives quant à la situation cachée à laquelle elle réfère ? Elle ne conviendrait plus si l'on peut donner quelque crédit à cela.

Comment: Il y a effectivement une connotation négative, mais plus que cela, il me semble surtout que "anguille sous roche" a une nuance que quelque chose se trame en cachette, "dans le dos", et qu'on n'ose pas le nommer précisément, comme par superstition. Si l'on veut "titiller" gentiment un couple, on peut donc utiliser l'expression comme s'ils cherchaient honteusement à cacher leurs projets de mariage,avec une touche d'ironie. Ce serait une manière de dire "mais que cachez-vous, petits coquins ?"

Comment: Et une variante humoristique: *il y a baleine sous gravillon*.

Comment: Je crois que l'on s'éloigne un peu trop de l'esprit de l'anglais en suivant votre voie et je dois dire que même si formulé d'une manière très atténuée « mais que cachez-vous, petits coquins? » ne convient pas ; cette sorte d'attitude est compatible avec des situations autres que celle-ci (enfants…) mais lorsqu'il s'agit de sentiments, qui peuvent être profonds , on ne peut que déplaire à des personnes dont on associe la relation d'amour qui les lie à de la coquinerie ; ne craignez-vous pas créer de telles impressions, d'être en fin de compte plutôt déplacé?

Comment: Mon exemple avec "coquins" était volontairement exagéré pour expliquer la touche ironique et la volonté de "titiller".... Tout dépend du contexte ! Je n'aurais aucune gêne à dire "y a-t-il anguille sous roche" à des amis que je soupçonne de vouloir se marier. Mais je ne l'utiliserai évidemment pas avec des inconnus, des voisins, avec mon patron, etc.

Comment: Oui, « anguille sous roche » est quand même assez vague quant aux allusions que l'on peut en extraire.

Answer (score 2):

- Je ne crois pas vous avoir jamais / Je crois ne vous avoir jamais... +

*- vus **chacun de son/votre côté**.*

*- vus autrement qu'ensemble.*

Comment: Yes, also: - *vus l'un sans l'autre.*

Answer (score 2):

A quite familiar way of saying it would be:

> Vous êtes toujours fourrés ensemble. / Je vous vois toujours fourrés ensemble.

And the next sentence could be one of those:

> Le mariage, c'est pour bientôt? / Il est peut être temps de penser au mariage? / Vous considérez vous marier bientôt?

Mainly depending on if you're suggesting it should be happening or just curious about their plans.

Edit: By the way, you are correct about the use of "séparés". Saying "Je ne vous ai jamais vu séparés." in this context would most likely be understood as something along the lines of "I've never seen you two break up / taking a break from each other"

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas vous avoir vu une seule fois l'un sans l'autre. Une nouvelle de mariage ne serait-elle pas en vue?

`ou légèrement relâché mais suffisamment correct`

Je ne crois pas vous avoir vu une seule fois l'un sans l'autre. Une nouvelle de mariage est en vue?

`autre possibilité sans trop de mots`

Vous êtes vraiment inséparables; le mariage, pour bientôt?

Answer (score 1):

For your first sentence, I think there is one form of the word “séparés” that you could use to capture the notion of “never [being/having been] apart” without implying (as does “séparés,” as you accurately point out) a “relationship going[/gone] bad,” and that would be its negative form [“inséparables.”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ins%C3%A9parables)

As an adjective, you could say:

> [On dirait que] Vous deux êtes [vraiment] [un couple] inséparables [,comme
>   Philémon et Baucis/comme Laurel et Hardy/comme un faire-part et son
>   enveloppe] !

(see *TLFi*’s entry for *inséparables* [as an adjective pertaining to people] below, via *CNRTL*):

> 2. En fonction d'épithète ou d'attribut, sans compl. de l'adj. [En parlant de deux ou de plusieurs pers. entre elles] Qui ne peuvent se
>      séparer l'une de l'autre ou les unes des autres, cesser d'être
>      ensemble, se quitter.
>      Deux amis inséparables; ils sont (devenus)
>      inséparables. Bientôt, nous deux, nous fûmes inséparables (CENDRARS,
>      Bourlinguer,1948, p. 199).

As a noun, you could say about the same thing and even get the benefit of the “Lovebirds” meaning of “inseparables” to boot:

> [On dirait que] Vous êtes deux [vrais] inséparables !

(see below, from the same *TLFi* entry for *inséparables* [as a noun pertaining to people] via *CNRTL*):

> Emploi subst. Au collège (...), dès leur huitième, il y avait eu les
>   trois inséparables, comme on les nommait (...). (ZOLA, Œuvres,1886, p.
>   34).

(and finally, from still the same *TLFi* entry for *inséparables* [as a noun extended by analogy to “lovebirds”] via *CNRTL*, there's):

> − P. anal., emploi subst. masc. ou fém. plur. Petites perruches
>   élevées par couples.

---

For your second sentence, I think all the other suggestions offered so far are good, although I tend to prefer @user168676 ‘s “news of a wedding/a wedding announcement perhaps being in sight/on the horizon.”

With this preference in mind for the notion of the possibility of a forthcoming wedding announcement, I think you could also consider the following variation of that notion (either with or without the parenthetical "word play") to use in that second line:

> Vous n'auriez pas un certain faire-part à envoyer (à faire partir) bientôt, par
>   hasard?

Comment: I fail to see the feebleness and what is unidiomatic as well the play on words, it's puzzling; except for the repetition of words (faire part/faire partir) that  one might prefer to avoid but that is  acceptable enough, I see nothing blatantly inharmonious; I wonder however if the touch of slight jocularity confered by not mentionning the particular nature of the faire-part would not be enhanced through a variant such as those: "Vous n'auriez pas un faire-part spécial à envoyer bientôt, par hasard?" *ou* "Vous n'auriez pas un certain faire-part  à envoyer bientôt, par hasard?".

Comment: On the contrary of what you purport, I believe your option well worth the consideration of a translator.

Comment: @user168676 Thanks, both for the supportive words and the good suggestions.  I’ve taken it all to heart and have edited accordingly.